# Why am I unable to use Okta hooks inside useEffect? (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-state, okta

Recently I posted a question in which I was having some conditional rendering issues with a React/Okta project using TypeScript (for context):

[Am I unable to use inline "if" with useEffect in a functional React component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68439160/am-i-unable-to-use-inline-if-with-useeffect-in-a-functional-react-component/68439215#68439215)

I've since solved that issue but now I'm experiencing another issue within the following component:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useOktaAuth } from '@okta/okta-react';
import { Dropdown } from 'semantic-ui-react';

import { UserInfo } from '../../interfaces/UserInfo';

export const HeaderUserMenu = () => {

    // Okta and State hooks
    const { authState, oktaAuth } = useOktaAuth();
    const [ userInfo, setUserInfo ] = useState<UserInfo>({});

    // Log current user data
    const logUser = () => {
        console.log(userInfo);
    }

    // Watch the auth state and user info for changes, update state.
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!authState || !authState.isAuthenticated) {
            setUserInfo({});
        } else {
            oktaAuth.getUser((info: UserInfo) => { 
                setUserInfo(info); 
            })
        }
    }, [authState, oktaAuth]);

    // If we have an empty user object, return nothing, otherwise...
    if (Object.keys(userInfo).length === 0) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return (
            <Dropdown item text={userInfo.name}>
                <Dropdown.Item onClick={logUser}>Log User</Dropdown.Item>
            </Dropdown>
        )
    }

}
```

When I successfully log into Okta, `authState` and `oktaAuth` in the `useOktaAuth()` hook should have stuff in them, and via `useState` and the `useEffect` hook, I should be able to fetch the current user's info.

However, it's seeming as if `authState` and `oktaAuth` from the hook aren't making it into the effect being run, so even though I'm currently logged into the app, this component is not being rendered at all.

Is it not possible to use hooks like this inside of an effect?  The documentation uses this exact pattern so I would have **assumed** this would be proper usage of `useOktaAuth()` and the Effect hook, but I can't get it working.

Also, one of the things I had to do to fix my previous issue was the addition of checking for `!authState` at the beginning of the effect, otherwise it -always- returns an error of:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'isAuthenticated' of null`

So I'm not sure if this has something to do with it?   There's NO reason that authState or oktaAuth should be null, unless the hook just isn't working?   Or there's some issue in combining that hook with useEffect.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Looking on the documentation on Okta' developer site here: https://developer.okta.com/code/react/okta_react/#create-a-custom-sign-in-form 
It looks like there is no 'authstate' variable you can retrieve. Can you try it without the 'authstate' variable or provide the current documentation you are using?